# How do I delete styles generated by a parent theme?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I create a website on Wordpress using a child theme. This is a child of the twentent theme. Sorry, but the site inherits the styles that I found in the . I found this using the browser development tools. These styles add a pink background to all .svg icons, e.g. the search icon. Or it changes the color of the headings. I would like to remove this effect, but I don't know how. Can anyone help me with this?

In another thread I read that these can be styles generated by the theme customizer. Is there a way to turn this off in a child theme?

Below I attach the link to the screenshot. Turning off this style sheet in the browser I get the effect I wanted, i.e. all headers and icons have the color that I defined in my style.css

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Either you should check if the colors can be changed in the Customizer (which shouldn't be that hard).

Or try to override the styles of the parent theme in the child's style.css

You can do this by copying the lines used in the parent theme and then changing the settings inside the `{  }` and adding that to the child style.css. Because your child theme style.css (should be) is included after the parent theme style.css, this should automatically override the parent theme style.

Comment: Yes, I can do it through a customizer. But the problem is that in the customizer all the elements are connected. Changes the background color of icons and the color of headers. A subassembly when each of these elements has a different color in the design.

Comment: That's why I think it would be best to disable the customizer, with its default colors, because in the future I want to create my own. But unfortunately I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I don't think its possible to turn it off. It is too much weaved into the code. Do you know how to override CSS? You can do this by making selectors more specific. If something is set by using !important, you need to use !important as well.

Comment: If the customizer has been enabled, you can definitely disable it. I added a declaration! Important. It worked. But it doesn't completely solve the complication, because I would like to disable customizer in child theme.

Comment: There is not really disabling/enabling of the customizer, it comes as part of the theme. What could happen is that you change settings in the parent theme, and then later activate a child theme and the customizer settings from the parent aren't being inherited to the child theme. I sometimes repair this for customers using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/ . But I am not sure if this is the problem in your case. You would enable parent theme, export settings in customizer menu, then enable child theme and import the settings.